# Performance of running Parallel.Foreach on several threads

Tags: c#, .net, performance, parallel-processing

I have 3 main processing threads, each of them performing operations on the values of ConcurrentDictionaries by means of Parallel.Foreach. The dictionaries vary in size from 1,000 elements to 250,000 elements

```
TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory();
Task t1 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
        Parallel.ForEach(dict1.Values, item => ProcessItem(item));
});

Task t2 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{                                
        Parallel.ForEach(dict2.Values, item => ProcessItem(item));
});

Task t3 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{                           
        Parallel.ForEach(dict3.Values, item => ProcessItem(item));
});
t1.Wait();
t2.Wait();
t3.Wait();
```

I compared the performance (total execution time) of this construct with just running the Parallel.Foreach in the main thread and the performance improved a lot (the execution time was reduced approximately 5 times)

My questions are:

1. Is there something wrong with the
   approach above? If yes, what and how
   can it be improved?
2. What is the reason for the different execution times?
3. What is a good way to debug/analyze such a situation?

**EDIT**: To further clarify the situation: I am mocking the client calls on a WCF service, that each comes on a separate thread (the reason for the Tasks). I also tried to use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem instead of Task, without a performance improvement. The objects in the dictionary have between 20 and 200 properties (just decimals and strings) and there is no I/O activity

I solved the problem by queuing the processing requests in a BlockingCollection and processing them one at the time

Comment: I suspect that the best performance in this situation will depend on the number of cores you have. Also, I'm not sure what the TPL will do if you queue up multiple tasks that are using multiple threads.

Comment: I run on a quad-core machine, 64bit operating system

Comment: What do you mean, "reduced approximately 5 times?" Do you mean that running it on the main thread takes 20% of the time that it takes to run multi-threaded?

Comment: @Jim Mischel. Yes. Running the 3 main processing threads running Parallel.Foreach takes around 5 seconds, while running Parallel.Foreach on the 3 dictionaries on the main thread takes 1 second

Comment: Perhaps make each thread do its job single-threaded?

Comment: ProcessItem reads the properties on the objects and does some simple math operations, storing them in concurrent dictionary with values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably over-parallelizing.

You don't need to create 3 tasks if you already use a good (and balanced) parallelization inside each one of them.

`Parallel.Foreach` already try to use the right number of threads to exploit the full CPU potential without saturating it. And by creating other tasks having `Parallel.Foreach` you're probably saturating it.
(EDIT: as [Henk said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398537/performance-of-running-parallel-foreach-on-several-threads/5398865#5398865), they probably have some problems in coordinating the number of threads to spawn when run in parallel, and at least this leads to a bigger overhead).

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392.aspx) for some hints.

Comment: I tried limiting the number of thread used by Parallel.Foreach by setting the MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3. I also tried using a custom scheduler to manage the threads, with minimal improvement in performance. What i do not understand is why I am over-parallelizing since these and another thread that polls the DB are the only threads i use in my application

Comment: @anchandra: On a quad-core you can just execute 4 threads concurrently. In this way (3 Tasks x 1-3 threads for Parallel.Foreach) you probably passing this numbers so threads are started/stopped slowing down the execution...

Comment: @anchandra: The point here ultimately is that you have 3 tasks of pure overhead which do nothing but call `Parallel.ForEach()`.  That uses up threads which could have been devoted to the worker threads.  Removing these might save you even more time since these tasks/threads would not be contending with the real worker threads for CPU time and context switching becomes less of a factor.

Comment: @Jeff: Not pure overhead perse. The scheduler is clever enough to let the the t1 Task/Thread do part of the ForEach when it's parked in t1.Wait()

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a Task is not a Thread.

Your `Parallel.ForEach()` calls are run by a scheduler that uses the ThreadPool and should try to optimize Thread usage. The ForEach applies a Partitioner.  When you run these in parallel they cannot coordinate very well.

Only if there is a performance problem, consider helping with extra tasks or DegreeOfParallelism directives. And then always profile and analyze first.

An explanation of your results is difficult, it could be caused by many factors (I/O for example) but the advantage of the 'single main task' is that the scheduler has more control and the CPU and Cache are used better (locality).

Answer (score 2):

The dictionaries vary widely in size and by the looks of it (given everything finishes in <5s) the amount of processing work is small. Without knowing more it's hard to say what's actually going on. How big are your dictionary items? The main thread scenario you're comparing this to looks like this right?

```
Parallel.ForEach(dict1.Values, item => ProcessItem(item)); 
Parallel.ForEach(dict2.Values, item => ProcessItem(item)); 
Parallel.ForEach(dict3.Values, item => ProcessItem(item));
```

By adding the Tasks around each ForEach your adding more overhead to manage the tasks and probably causing memory contention as dict1, dict2 and dict3 all try and be in memory and hot in cache at the same time. Remember, CPU cycles are cheap, cache misses are not.